# SharePoint 2013 Use Only Always Suggest

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

In SharePoint 2013 the system automatically makes the query suggestions when users search a keyword and click a link 6 or more times. In addition, you can add the Always Suggest Phrases by importing the text file that is separated by line breaks.

Is there a way to disable and remove all the automatic query suggestions and only use the Always Suggest Phrase?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on technet and it appears there is no way around this.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f486b8ba-f706-4c80-9cda-0b63116ef6a6/sharepoint-2013-use-only-always-suggest?forum=sharepointsearch